# Javascript/jQuery replace recuring span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm not good at regex, I need help on this problem.

1) I want to mimic bbcode, replacing the span tag in html text.

## HTML format

```
thtml= 'this the text content <span style="color: #000;">color this text</span> with mutiple span like this <span style="color: #000;">second span</span> and more';
```

Code:

```
thtml.replace('[','<span style="color: #000;">');
thtml.replace(']','</span>');
```

Using that code it just replaces only once.

```
'this the text content [color this text] with mutiple span like this <span style="color: #000;">second span </span> and more';
```

## Result I want:

```
'this the text content [color this text] with mutiple span like this [second span] and more';
```

2) If possible also revert from the last format back to the source HTML format at the beginning.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your code which you tried in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
thtmk.replace(/\<span style\=\"color\: \#000\;\"\>/g,'[')
thtmk.replace(/\<\/span\>/g,']')
```

will it work for you?

Comment: between slashes and add a g at the end is the way to do it. g means global or all instances in the string.

Comment: thank you it's working.. and i can get the revert back to html with:
`thtml.replace(/\[/g,'<span style="color: #ff6600;">');`
`thtml.replace(/\]/g,'</span>');`

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular Expressions

HTML PAGE

```
<div id="t">this the text [content color this text] with mutiple span like this [second span] and more;</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="submit" />
<div id="t1"></div>
<br/>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        var thtml = $('#t').text();

        var thtml1 = thtml.replace(/\[/g, '<span style="color: blue;">');
        var thtml2 = thtml1.replace(/\]/g, '</span>');
        $('#t1').html(thtml2);

    });

});
```

it replace all occurrence of '[' and ']'

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/gCBFu/